How do short circuit operators decide how the statement is interpreted?
I have just learned about short circuit operators in C that if the result can be deduced from the left statement the right statement is not run. However, if there are more than one of these operators, what decides which statement is part of which? Such as the code below, if according to operator precendence && is higher than || that wouldn't the left part be (a+b)%d while d++||c++ be the other part? Because if I ran the program and checked the values of d and c after, the value of d is not incremented while c is, which means c++ was done? Why does this happen?
int main()
{
    int a=5,b=8,c=0,d=1;
    printf("%d\n",(a+b)%d&&d++||c++);
    printf("%d %d",c,d);
    return 0;
}


High precedence means the opposite of that.

How? I'm not sure what you mean.

Unrelated: note that your expression uses both d and d++ and that, by itself, is a big NO-NO. In this specific example there's a sequence point in between (the &&) so it isn't Undefined Behaviour... but, in general, avoid mixing var and var++ (or similar) in the same expression (even when using parenthesis).

@VTG: The operands would only be grouped the way you're grouping them if && had lower precedence than ||.

As a rule of thumb, if you have to ask what the code does, just don't write code like that! Even if the compiler knows the rules, we poor humans might not.

@BoP And that's why code such as (a+b)%d&&d++||c++ should fail any code review.  And even if you know what it does now, when you look at it again next year - or even next week - there's a good chance you won't know.  And pity the poor soul who has to maintain it five years from now.  It's always fun after you look at code and think, "Who's the idiot who wrote this?!?!" then have git blame spit out your name.

It might be easier if you think about which operand each logical operator got. In this case the operators of && are (a+b)%d and d++. That there is an || elsewhere in the same expression is irrelevant for &&. The operands of the || are however (a+b)%d && d++ and c++.

As for everyone saying "don't write code like that", I would add that exercises seeking to teach you operator precedence are mildly interesting. Knowing it is helpful sure, but there are so many far more important things to learn, like proper program design. If you know the precedence of the mathematical operators (which you already should long before picking up programming), then that gets you quite far. There's no shame in having a "precedence table" to peek at while coding.

&& does indeed have a higher precedence over ||, meaning that && will be evaluated first.
However, the result of (a+b)%d is going to be 0. Because the division rest between 13 and 1 is 0, which evaluates in C as false. In this case, the right operand of the && (the d++) will no longer be executed.
|| is then going to be evaluated. The left operand will have a result of 0, meaning that c++ (the right operand) also needs to be evaluated. And this is why it is incremented.

&& has higher precedence than ||, so an expression like
a && b || c

will be parsed as
(a && b) || c

c will only be evaluated if a && b evaluates to zero.
Both && and || force left-to-right evaluation.  a will be evaluated first and all side effects will be applied; if the result is non-zero then b will be evaluated and all side effects applied.  If the result of a && b is non-zero, then c will not be evaluated.
